# Is there a way to create Grafana template variable using instant query?

Tags: grafana

My use case is to query labels only for non-absent metric.

```
label_values(memory_usage,name)
```

The problem is the result will contain 'name' labels for metrics which are absent (metrics comes from cadvisor, so stopped containers' metric will be absent but present as a timeseries).

On prometheus side I can solve this by invoking memory_usage on api/v1/query instead of api/v1/query_range,grafana handle this as well but only on the dashbaord panels where we have an 'instant' checkbox.

But how can I do this when defining template variable?

So I need something like this:

```
label_values(memory_usage *if memory usage non-absent for label name*,name)
```

or

```
label_values(memory_usage *instant*,name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.

As you mention, using the `label_values(...)` function in the variable query field does ranged queries. But as explained [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/prometheus/#templating), you can use `query_result(query)` to perform an instant query.

This will return a list of metrics, but cannot be combined with `label_values(...)`. Using the [regex field](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/filter-variables-with-regex/#filter-and-modify-using-named-text-and-value-capture-groups), you can extract labels from these metrics.

For example:

- Query: `query_result(kafka_controller_kafkacontroller_activecontrollercount_value{} )`
- Regex: `/.*instance="(?<value>[\d\.:]+)".*/`
- Resulting values: `10.244.120.121:5556`, `10.244.120.87:5556`, `10.244.120.97:5556`

For reference, the output using `label_values`:

- Query: `label_values(kafka_controller_kafkacontroller_activecontrollercount_value{}, instance)`
- Regex: none
- Resulting values: `10.244.120.121:5556`, `10.244.120.87:5556`, `10.244.120.93:5556`, `10.244.120.97:5556` (this includes a stopped pod)